# Exam class: aligning outline marks within solution flush right

Tags: align, exam

I would like to get the marks e.g. [1/2] within the solution to appear flush right in the same way as the overall mark for the question.

```
\documentclass[11pt,answers]{exam}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace, amsthm}
\RequirePackage{tikz, pgflibraryplotmarks, esint}

\begin{document} 

\begin{questions}
\pointsdroppedatright
\bracketedpoints

\question[1]
Differentiate 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=x^3-2x
\end{equation*}
and evaluate at $x=0$ \droppoints

\begin{solution}
\begin{gather*}
f^{\prime}(x)=3x^2-2 \text{ [$\frac{1}{2}$]} \\
f^{\prime}(0)=-2 \text{ [$\frac{1}{2}$]}
\end{gather*}
\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I introduce `\answermarks[]{}`.  The first optional argument, default `1`, is the mark, and the second argument is the equation to be set.

Note: I took the liberty of making the mark on the right in `\textstyle`.  To restore it to `\displaystyle`, merely change `$#1$` to `$\displaystyle#1$` in the definition of `\answermarks`.

To get the marks just inside the box, change the `+2.4cm` to `-1cm` in the definition of `\fulltextwidth`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,answers]{exam}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace, amsthm}
\RequirePackage{tikz, pgflibraryplotmarks, esint}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\fulltextwidth
\fulltextwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth+2.4cm\relax
\newcommand\answermarks[2][1]{\def\stacktype{L}\def\useanchorwidth{T}\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackon[0pt]{\displaystyle\vphantom{#1}#2}{\hspace{\fulltextwidth}\llap{\text{ [$#1$]}}}%
}}
\begin{document} 
\begin{questions}
\pointsdroppedatright
\bracketedpoints
\question[1]
Differentiate 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=x^3-2x
\end{equation*}
and evaluate at $x=0$ \droppoints
\begin{solution}
\begin{gather*}
  \answermarks[\frac{1}{2}]{f^{\prime}(x)=3x^2-2} \\
  \answermarks[\frac{1}{2}]{f^{\prime}(0)=-2}
\end{gather*}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you so much. I did indeed want it in text style.